# Force yarn to ignore npm config

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

I don't want `yarn` to use my npm config. Specifically, I want it to ignore my npm registry because I use a custom one for work, which fails if I'm not on the VPN.

I know I can swap the registry out in about 5 seconds, but I imagine it's possible to separate yarn/npm configs.

Comment: I'm trying to bypass my work npm too. Do you have any progress on this?

Comment: Not yet. I can get around it by swapping my registry.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. My NPM environment is configured for a Work registry and can only be accessed over VPN and so my add/install commands just hang until I get the network connection output.

My solution has been to create a `.npmrc` file within the project directory and set the registry to the same as yarn's, e.g.:

```
# inside of my-project-root/.npmrc
registry=https://registry.yarnpkg.com
```

Answer (score -1):

Yarn comes with the default yarn registry (https://registry.yarnpkg.com). The problem you can't install via yarn is probably because of your SSL? try `yarn config set strict-ssl false` and see if that works